# Prove of the farthest pair

Tags: graph

For a graph G = (V, E) we denote the length of the shortest path between
vertices u, v ∈ V by dG(u, v). The diameter of G is defined as ∆(G) = maxu,v∈V dG(u, v). A pair of vertices (u, v) that realizes the diameter is called a farthest pair.

Let u be any vertex of G and let v be a vertex that is farthest away from u
in G (i.e. maximizes dG(u, v)). Prove that, if G is an undirected tree, then v is part of a farthest pair of G.

That is the question and I have to do the prove. I assumed that there is a existence of a farthest pair (x, y) such that dG(u, v), dG(x, v), and dG(y, v) are smaller than dG(x, y). I'm trying to find a contradition out of it, by assuming that v is not a farthest pair of G.

**If v is part of the farthest pair of G:**
There exist a v' such that Dg(v, v') >= Dg(X, Y)

**If v is not part of the farthest pair of the, we negate the statement above. Using De Morgan, we get:**

For all v': not( Dg(v, v') >= Dg(X, Y) ).

For all v': Dg(v, v') < Dg(X, Y).

**So now I have three statements**
(x,y) is the farthest pair.

For all v': Dg(v, v') < Dg(X, Y).

v is the furthest from u.

How do I continue with the prove to prove what has to be proven?
(if G is an undirected tree, then v is part of a farthest pair of G.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming but computer science

Answer (score 0):

Your question is actually an exact duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209922/furthest-distance-vertices-undirected-tree

Comment: Uhm, nope it is not for tonight 12:00.

Comment: No worries then, I'll post the answer tomorrow :)

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand two things: Why I couldn't find it when I use the search function and why you didn't give me it earlier.

Comment: Ralphie can you please mark this as a final solution (or duplicate)? Thanks.